# I'm using axios to get data from the server and storing it in the state. When I do setAPIData(response.data.highlighting); I do not see anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, axios, mern

`Searchbar.jsx:69 Uncaught TypeError: APIData.map is not a function`

I want to print an object value. I'm using Express, solr, React and Axios.

I'm using axios to get data from the server and storing it in this.state.posts. When I do `console.log(response.data.highlighting)` in, it logs the posts array perfectly. But when I do the same in `render(){ return ( /*here*/)}` it does not show anything.

```
axios call like this:

 const handleSearch = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        return await axios.get(`http://localhost:8983/solr/pathfinder/select?indent=true&q.op=OR&q=title%3A${searchInput}%20OR%20para%3A${searchInput}`)
            .then((response) => {
               //  console.log(response.data.highlighting);
                setAPIData(response.data.highlighting);
                setSearchInput("");
            })
        //  .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    }



  <div>
                <Container id="Search-container" >
                    <input id="searchInput" type="text" placeholder="Search here..." className="search" value={searchInput} onChange={(event) => {
                        setSearchInput(event.target.value);
                    }} />
                    <Button className="primary" onClick={handleSearch} >Search</Button>
                    {/* <Button className="primary">Search</Button> */}
                    <Helpbar />
                    <Button className="my-epc" primary>MYEPC</Button>
                </Container>
            </div>
            <Container id='result-filter'>
                <div className="main-conatiner">
                    {searchInput.length > 1 ? (
                        filteredResults.map((item) => {
                            return (
                                <div className="id-result" key={item.id}>
                                    <div id="heading-result">
                                        <h2 key={item.id} className="heder-result">{item.title}</h2>
                                         {/* <img id="pdficon" src={pdficon} alt="download pdf" height="20px" /> */}
                                         
                                    </div>
                                    <hr className="hr-result" />
                                       
                                    <p className="para-result" key={item.id}>{item.para}</p>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })

                    ) : (
                        APIData.map((item) => {
                            return (

                                <div className="id-result" key={item.id}>
                                    <div id="heading-result">
                                        <h2 key={item.id} className="heder-result">{item.title}</h2>
                                        {/* <img id="pdficon" src={pdficon} alt="download pdf" height="20px" /> */}
                                        <Button className="download-button"><PDFReader/></Button> 
                                    </div>
                                    <hr className="hr-result" />
                                     <p  className="para-result" key={item.id}>{item.para}</p>                             
                                      </div> 
                                
                            )

                        })
                    )}

                </div>
            </Container>
```

Comment: What is the initial state of `APIData`?

Comment: function Serachbar() {
    const [APIData, setAPIData] = useState([])
    const [filteredResults] = useState([]);
    const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState("");

Comment: Can you show the result of `console.log(response.data);` after the `axios` call?

Comment: {responseHeader: {…}, response: {…}, facet_counts: {…}, highlighting: {…}, spellcheck: {…}, …}

Comment: Please update the question instead of posting code in the comments. So not everyone has to read the whole conversation.